# Web Console threats

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Can google engineers see or access what's within my account's VM, and how can I be sure if this isn't the case? But, assuming that's the case, what tools do your engineers have in case of VM troubleshooting?

Comment: The answer is yes, Google can access your account. In some cases, you must manually approve Google's access. Google has written policies regarding this and logs that record what actions Google performs. This is called **Access Transparency** https://cloud.google.com/cloud-provider-access-management/access-transparency/docs/overview

Answer (score 0):

According to their "Customer data is your data, not Google’s."[privacy policy](https://cloud.google.com/privacy)

You should disable root access via SSH, and change default username/password that they provide for initial access, if you are still don't trust them.

Comment: What about the web console they can observe the live session without need to access my VM?

Comment: You should not use web console, simple as that. Always use SSH to authenticate to ensure communication is encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

The generally accepted simplification is that whatever safeguards and encryption you built into your software, they will not protect you from a determined adversary that has full control over the hardware where your software is running.

So in that regard Google Cloud engineers could, in theory, be able to access your data. (Without your knowledge and consent)

In practice Google, like other reputable providers, has internal security and process procedures, checks and controls that are designed to prevent that.

Those should be audited regularly by an external, independent third party to help you decide if you can and are willing to trust them.

Decide for yourself https://cloud.google.com/security/compliance